# Why do i get a numerical error when my csv data i loaded is numeric?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to plot the data from a csv file and i am getting this error saying "ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric". What can i do to relieve the issue and turn my code which are numbers in the csv files, to integers for python?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df  = pd.read_csv("car_data.csv")
df.plot()  # plots all columns against index
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='horsepower',y='price') # scatter plot
df.plot(kind='density')  # estimate density function

ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric
```

Data:

```
make fuel_type aspiration num_of_doors body_style drive_wheels engine_location wheel_base length width height curb_weight engine_type num_of_cylinders engine_size fuel_system compression_ratio horsepower peak_rpm city_mpg highway_mpg price 
1 alfa-romero gas std two convertible rwd front 88.6 168.8 64.1 48.8 2548 dohc four 130 mpfi 9 111 5000 21 27 13495 
2 alfa-romero gas std two convertible rwd front 88.6 168.8 64.1
```

Comment: Do you have an example snippet of your csv file?

Comment: Use df.info() to check types

Comment: Show `df.dtypes`

Comment: In your data, make is "alfa-romero" which is not numeric, as the error message notes.  Btw, it would be much better for future questions if you put the data in the question itself and not in a comment, where it is hard to read.

Comment: @JohnE the scatter plot is being called on `horsepower` and `price`, not `make`.  Both of those columns should be numeric.

Comment: @pduvi All of the plots will automatically only plot numeric data. `df.plot()` and `df.plot.density()` will plot all the columns that are numeric.  For some reason, `read_csv` is not reading any of the data in as numeric.  Perhaps you have an older version of `pandas`, which you should try to update.  Alternatively, all of your columns that should only be numeric, also have text.

Comment: `pandas` makes object dtype columns for various reasons.  Even if the values in a column are all numeric, if the dtype is `object`, `plt` will still raise this error.  Especially when making a dataframe from a `csv` you need to examine the frame. Don't just assume that it was loaded in a particular way.

Answer (score 1):

- Given the provided sample data, if I create `car_data.csv` and create a `df` with `pd.read_csv('car_data.csv')`, the expected columns are read in properly as `float64` and the remainder as `objects`.
- For some reason, the `dtypes` don't appear to be set correctly during creation of `df`.
- Fix the `dtypes` with the following code.

### Fix `dtypes`:

```py
df  = pd.read_csv("car_data.csv")

for col in df.columns:
    try:
        df = df.astype({col: 'float'})
    except ValueError:
        print(f'The following column could not be converted to float: {col}')
```

#### Output of loop:

```
The following column could not be converted to float: make
The following column could not be converted to float: fuel_type
The following column could not be converted to float: aspiration
The following column could not be converted to float: num_of_doors
The following column could not be converted to float: body_style
The following column could not be converted to float: drive_wheels
The following column could not be converted to float: engine_location
The following column could not be converted to float: engine_type
The following column could not be converted to float: num_of_cylinders
The following column could not be converted to float: fuel_system
```

- The other columns should be converted to `float64` as per:

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 22 columns):
make                 2 non-null object
fuel_type            2 non-null object
aspiration           2 non-null object
num_of_doors         2 non-null object
body_style           2 non-null object
drive_wheels         2 non-null object
engine_location      2 non-null object
wheel_base           2 non-null float64
length               2 non-null float64
width                2 non-null float64
height               1 non-null float64
curb_weight          1 non-null float64
engine_type          1 non-null object
num_of_cylinders     1 non-null object
engine_size          1 non-null float64
fuel_system          1 non-null object
compression_ratio    1 non-null float64
horsepower           1 non-null float64
peak_rpm             1 non-null float64
city_mpg             1 non-null float64
highway_mpg          1 non-null float64
price                1 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(12), object(10)
memory usage: 480.0+ bytes
```

- After fixing the `dtypes`, plotting should work as expected for the following.

```
df.plot()  # plots all columns against index
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='horsepower', y='price') # scatter plot
df.plot(kind='density')  # estimate density function
```